# PHP Match at least two genres (mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, match

I am creating a simple movie database, where i have three tables:

movie

> with movie_id, movie_name, movie_year

---

genre

> with genre_id, genre_name

---

movie_genre (for many to many association)

> with idgenre, idmovie

I made the associations between movies and genres like:

```
Movie id    Genre id
    1           1
    1           2
    2           4
    2           1
```

So, a movie can have more genres. Now, in a single.php page, where I retrieve a movie id and print the informations about this movie, I also want to print only movies that match at least two genres, like:

> Movie id = 1 ==> (ex. Titanic, Genres: Drama, Romantic, Adventure)

Now the php script should print all the movies that match at least 2 genres, so if there is a movie that has Genres: Drama, Adventure it should be printed...

Could anyone help me in doing this? What should be the php query?
Thanks in advance :D

Comment: put a another query in the where clause, ie WHERE (select COUNT(*) ... ) > 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  movie_id, movie_name, movie_year, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT genre.genre_name)
FROM movies
JOIN movie_genre
  ON movie_genre.idmovie = movies.movie_id
JOIN genre
  ON genre.genre_id = movie_genre.idgenre
  AND genre.genre_name IN ('Drama','Adventure')
GROUP BY movie_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT movie_genre.idgenre) >= 2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I was using JOIN and COUNT too, but not in the same way, this works and now I understand how to work with joins...
Thank you again :D